# Objective-C: How to switch the NSView by button click

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I have different xib files with NSViewController attached to them. (Screenshot below)

[image]

One of xib file called StartMenuViewController which has a button. I want to click that button and change the view to DetectingUSBViewController.(Screenshot below)
The IBAction of that button is in StartMenuViewController.m file.

[image]

And I use AppController.m to control my main xib view.(NSWindow + NSView) (Screenshot below)
[image]

When the application runs, I try to initialize the StartMenuViewController fist by doing the following thing in my AppController.m file.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{   
    [self initialize];
}

-(void) initialize
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        //mainViewController is a NSViewController and _mainView is a NSView which connect with Custom View in main xib
        self.mainViewController = [[[StartMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:StartMenuView bundle:nil]autorelease];
        [_mainView addSubview:[_mainViewController view]];
    }
}
```

It works fine and it will show the StartMenuViewController.xib on the window at first, but I do not know how to change the view after clicking the button(FIND USB DRIVE). I want the current view changes to DetectingUSBViewController.xib.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way possible, assuming you have tied your USB button properly in, do the following :

```
- (IBAction)usbButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    DetectingUSBViewController *second = [[DetectingUSBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetectingUSBView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Is this for mac or for ios?

Comment: This is for iOS. Not sure if this is applicable to mac as well.

Comment: No it doesn't work on osx as there is no presentViewController method

Comment: But the approach is correct otherwise. Do an addSubview instead

Answer (score 0):

load the DetectingUSBViewController in `startMenuViewController` as     `DetectingUSBViewController* v1 = [[ViewCont1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewCont1" bundle:nil];`  now add or replace the view as `[v1 view]` in view where you want to add/replace.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to hook up your button to send an IBAction
2. You need a 'View for DetectingUSBViewController.xib'
   => one way (iOS like) is to use a ViewController. Subclass NSViewController and then alloc init a DetectingUSBViewController
3. Add the view. Don't present the VC (as there is no such thing in OSX)

---

```
//button click action
- (IBAction)usbButton:(UIButton *)sender {
     //! Retain the VC
     Self.detectingUSBViewController = [[DetectingUSBViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetectingUSBView" bundle:nil];

     //add the view
     [_mainView addSubview:[_detectingUSBViewController view]];
```

}

Comment: The _mainView is in AppController class rather than StartViewController class. How to call _mainView in here? Thanks